# Relative invariant w.r.t. $Xf$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

$$x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mbox{   (independent variables)}$$ 
$$y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mbox{   (dependent variables)}$$

$$f=f(x,y)$$

It is said that $f$ is invariant, or absolute invariant iff

$$Xf=0,$$ where X is the infinitesimal transformation symbol/operator, corresponding to a one-parameter Lie group. Let $\varphi=\varphi(x,y)$ is relative invariant. Then

$$X\varphi = ?$$

Some say that $X\varphi=0$ when $\varphi=0$. This is confusing...

Can someone explain,

$$X\varphi = ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think about an invariant as a function that is constant on orbits of $X$. While an absolute invariant is constant on every orbit, a relative invariant may be constant only on some orbits (all absolute invariants are relative invariants).

For example, let $X= x \partial_x$ be a vector field on $\mathbb R$. There are three orbits: $(-\infty,0),\{0\},(0,\infty)$. The only absolute invariants are the constant functions $f\equiv C \in \mathbb R$  (constant functions are always invariants). However, we do have a relative invariant $\varphi(x) = x$, because $ X \varphi=x \partial_x (x) = x$ which is zero when $\varphi=x=0$.